# Converting Unicode text into ASCII adds extra characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, clplacemark

I have this raw string `101\U2013113 W 4th St`.

Which should read `101-113 W 4th St`

This string comes from a `CLPlacemark`

`placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"]`

However, when I decode it with:

```
NSData *decode = [placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString * address =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decode encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

It outputs some extra characters at the beginning of the string that I can't paste here but an NSLog shows `"\U00ff\U00fe101\^S 113 W 4th St Chattanooga TN 37402";`

If I `NSLog` the placemark, it reads as it should `101-113 W 4th St`

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: You're using the wrong encoding. It's UTF8. And what's in the address dictionary is already strings; there is no need to decode anything. And, since `addressDictionary` is deprecated, that's wrong too.

Comment: I need to support back to iOS 9. You are correct. I need to use `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

Everything. `addressDictionary` is deprecated, and there is no need to decode any data in any case; the address information already comes to you as a string. (It's unclear what a "raw" string is supposed to be; a string is a string.) You cannot convert the string to ASCII, as it may (and here does) contains nonASCII characters. Just use the string you're given.

A CLPlacemark has properties such as `subthoroughfare` (a house number) and `thoroughfare` (a street name), or if you want the address as a whole, get its `postalAddress` and format with a CNPostalAddressFormatter (you'll need to import the Contacts framework).

Comment: I need to support back as far as iOS 9. Additionally, I need to drop the Country from the address. So I was formatting my own string. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Then you should use conditional code (conditional on the system being used at runtime) and do both — use `addressDictionary` for iOS 10 and before, and `postalAddress` or other properties for iOS 11